# Database design: How can you represent conditions in a relationship?

Tags: database, database-design

There are situations where, according to a condition, a type of entity must be associated with another type of entity, for example:

1. There is a `car entity` that can be of different `types`, it can be a public service car such as a cab or it can be a private car(family car).
2. Depending on the type of car, you may have `obligations(this is the way I represent the taxes on a car)` to pay. If you have a private car you need to pay a tax year by year, but for example in some countries cabs or public cars must pay additional taxes to provide the service of transporting passengers in a certain city.
3. Both types of car share certain obligations(taxes), that no matter what kind of car it is, private or public, it must pay. But each type of car can have its own obligation(taxes) types to pay.

#### Condition

Depending on the type of vehicle a type of taxes/obligations must be paid. If it is a private car you will relate the normal tax, but if it is a public car you will relate the normal tax, plus an additional one for the transport of passengers. **how can I represent these kinds of conditions in a database model?**

#### What I've tried

[image]

I'm not sure if it's the right way to represent this type of condition, but I'm using an intermediate table that I call `obligation_type_of_car`, which associates the `type of car` with the `type of obligation`. I'm also not sure what cardinalities to place from this intermediate table to the other tables.

#### update

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to map obligation to cartype, as it is tied to cartype.

obligationtype is not related to cartype. So, it is better to leave it from the cartype_obligation table. You can derive obligationtype from obligation table.

- car
- car_type
- obligation
- obligation_type
- New table: Cartype_obligation

  - car_type_id
  - obligation_id

Comment: you can explain this further:  `You can derive obligationtype from obligation table.`

Comment: @CristianCamiloFlórez, from obligation_id, we can see what obligation_type it belongs to

Comment: And what about carinalities? one-to-one from Cartype_obligation to the car_type_id, and the same for obligation_id. I update my question. Other thing I put the car_license_plate in the obligation table, Is this necessary If I'm connecting the obligation to the type of car?

Comment: @CristianCamiloFlórez, I feel that you should not have car_license_plate in the obligation table. because, obligation is at car_type level. It is not at car level. `car -> cartype -> cartype_obligation -> obligration -> obligationtype`

Comment: but there are obligations that share any kind of car. Wouldn't it be better to handle it at car level? because every obligation must have a car plate so you can know which car it belongs to.

Comment: @CristianCamiloFlórez, In that case, we need to have the table as `car_obligation`, instead of `cartype_obligation`. don't repeat the information in multiple tables. All the car information should be in the `car` table. so, `car -> cartype`. `obligation-> obligationtype`. `car_obligation` (mapping car with corresponding obligation)

Comment: I'm a little confusing with the above answer: having `car_obligation` table, It involves a many-to-many relationship? if that is the case a car can have multiple obligations and that is true but one obligation can belong to multiple cars?

Comment: @CristianCamiloFlórez, sorry. I did not know about your object model. In that case, it makes sense to keep `car_id` in the `obligation` table, to make way for one to many relationship.